# how to get items randomly out of an array without any loop php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

hello all i am having this design in my web page

[image]

i want different images in each of the block each time the page refreshes the images changes in each block
like image1 in block 1 and image2 in block 2 and so on i can not use loop as the divs here are not the same i have this particular pattern

i can get the images from my database and stored in an array but i have no idea how to place them in these divs individual to be distinct from each other

see my code below

```
   $getimages=mysqli_query($conn,"select uid,vname,thumb,views from 
   tablename where something !='0' and somethingelse !='' order by rand()   limit 21");
   $Results = array();
   while($tmp=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getimages)){
   $Results[] = array('uid' => $tmp['uid'], 
   'vname' => $tmp['vname'], 'thumb' => $tmp['thumb']);
     }
    $i=randim('13');
     function randim($code){
    return rand(0,10);
     }
```

please give me some hints to solve this i want individual images in each of the block i can not use loop as the divs are non repetative

in my div i am calling images as

```
  <div class="somethingddd" style="background:url('mem/<?=$Results[$i]['uid']?>/img/<?=$Results[$i]['thumb']?>');background-size:cover;">

            </div>
```

Comment: I think you can use http://desandro.github.io/masonry/

Comment: use array_shuffle to randomize the order of your array then array_pop to get elements off the array for each usage

Comment: @Orangepill thankyou for the comment but can you plaease post it as an answer with some more hints please .....

Comment: @JasbirSinghSohanpal i dont want the the design i have it i want the random images from the array inside the divs ..

Comment: would be there always 7 div blocks and each block will have 1 image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way that I can think of is to shuffle your array then use fixed offsets to get each positional element.

```
<?php
    shuffle($Results);
?>
<div class="position0" style="background:url('mem/<?=$Results[0]['uid']?>/img/<?=$Results[0]['thumb']?>');"></div>
<div class="position1" style="background:url('mem/<?=$Results[1]['uid']?>/img/<?=$Results[0]['thumb']?>');"></div>
<div class="position2" style="background:url('mem/<?=$Results[2]['uid']?>/img/<?=$Results[0]['thumb']?>');"></div>
<div class="position3" style="background:url('mem/<?=$Results[3]['uid']?>/img/<?=$Results[0]['thumb']?>');"></div>
<div class="position4" style="background:url('mem/<?=$Results[4]['uid']?>/img/<?=$Results[0]['thumb']?>');"></div>
<div class="position5" style="background:url('mem/<?=$Results[5]['uid']?>/img/<?=$Results[0]['thumb']?>');"></div>
<div class="position6" style="background:url('mem/<?=$Results[6]['uid']?>/img/<?=$Results[0]['thumb']?>');"></div>
```

Then in your css you can have the styles associated with each of the position based on the class name.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following after the `while` loop:

```
shuffle($Results);
```

Good luck!